# Min Lines not working when inputType is given in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Anybody have come across with this situation. I need to show minimum 4 lines for edittext and when minLines given itworks fine But when add inputType tag to it , Min Lines fails..

```
          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/my_review_review_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                android:background="@drawable/rect"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Add a review"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:minLines="4"
                android:padding="10dp" />
```

Please correct me if am wrong and provide me a solution....

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use 
            `android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/notes_box"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:lines="5"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"/>
```

Comment: Have you used
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"

Comment: yes...textMultiline works...
can you explain me why this fails
"android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect""

Comment: | is a pipe operator. It concats all the option you are providing. the "textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect" means the flags textCapSentences and textMultiLine and textAutoCorrect are on for inputType

Answer (score 4):

Try it..

```
      <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line has been removed

```
android:inputType = "textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
```

Comment: oh..i need that and by adding "textMultiline" for inPutType using pipe operator we can achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply adding inputType as MultiLine along with other inputTypes

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:minLines="6"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
```